# react-native-svg doesn't detect transparent color

Tags: react-native, svg, radial-gradients

I am facing an annoying issue using react-native-svg to implement a radial gradient that from grey has a transparent color.

For some reason I can still see a grey-ish tint on the center of the gradient, that is supposed to be transparent, in order to see the image below without any color on top.

This is the code I am using:

```
 <Svg
          height="700"
          width="1000"
          style={{ position: "absolute", left: -400, top: -350 }}
        >
          <Defs>
            <RadialGradient
              id="cardCircleGradient"
              cx="600"
              cy="600"
              rx="600"
              ry="600"
              fx="600"
              fy="600"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            >
              <Stop offset="0" stopColor="#00000000" stopOpacity="0" /> <-HERE is where I cannot implement a transparent color
              <Stop
                offset="1"
                stopColor="rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.45)"
                stopOpacity="1"
              />
            </RadialGradient>
          </Defs>
          <Circle cx="600" cy="600" r="600" fill="url(#cardCircleGradient)" />
        </Svg>
```

Did someone experience a similar issue?

Comment: You might want to add <Stop offset="0.01" stopColor="#000000" stopOpacity="0" /> Just so there's a tiny bit of gradient that is going from no color to no color.

Comment: @MichaelMullany no success with that solution.

Comment: Well visually, the center looks grey, but that's an optical/contrast effect. If you use a color-picker, there is actually a few pixels of transparent black in the center of the gradient. If you want it to be more noticeable then adjust the 0.01 to .1

Comment: @MichaelMullany now I can see a slight difference. Thank you very much.